# Find equal spacing between points on a rectangle

Tags: rectangles

I'm trying to figure out how to equally space bolts around a rectangular piece of wood.

The board measures 29 7/8" tall by 24" wide. I would like a 1.25" edge margin on all sides with 6 bolts going down the long side and 5 bolts going across the shorter side.

Is there an easy way to figure spacing out to where each bolt is equally spaced around the entire board?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The long side measures $29.875in$, you want $1.25in$ of space either side, so you have $29.875-1.25-1.25=27.375in$ of space to share between 6 bolts. Then to spread these evenly, you divide by 5 (because you want to split up into 6 bolts, therefore 5 gaps). Here's a diagram to see what I mean:  $$|-|-|-|-|-|$$
The $|$'s are the bolts, the $-$ are the distances. There are $5$ $-$'s. $$\dfrac{27.375}{5}=5.475in$$
So on the long side, they are places that far apart.

You can then do calculations similarly for the short side.